# Does the Shadow Magic sorcerer's Eyes of the Dark feature negate Sunlight Sensitivity for creatures like drow?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, racial-traits, vision-and-light, drow

The [Shadow Magic sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#ShadowMagic)'s 1st-level feature [Eyes of the Dark](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#EyesoftheDark-750) reads (XGtE, p. 51):

> Starting at 1st level, you have darkvision with a range of 120 feet.

I would like to play a Drow character. Does Eyes of the Dark negate Sunlight Sensitivity, since you are getting superior darkvision from a new source that does not provide Sunlight Sensitivity?

I have heard that the warlock's Devil's Sight provides a similar effect that negates Sunlight Sensitivity; would this also apply to the Shadow Magic sorcerer?

Answer (score 15):

### Sunlight Sensitivity will still apply.

There's no mechanical connection between the Drow Superior Darkvision trait and the Sunlight Sensitivity trait, so getting improved darkvision from another source has no effect on Sunlight Sensitivity. Neither Devil Sight nor Eyes of the Dark say anything about changing how your vision works in sunlight; none of these traits do anything to prevent the disadvantage of Sunlight Sensitivity.

The Shadow Sorcerer does allow a workaround, though: the Eyes of the Dark trait also allows you to cast Darkness that doesn't block your own vision. If you use this feature to place a Darkness effect that catches yourself and your target, neither will be in direct sunlight so Sunlight Sensitivity doesn't apply. This will cause problems for your allies, though.

Answer (score 6):

## No it does not

Having darkvision, superior or not, do not cancel sunlight sensitivity. That is the racial trait of drows. That character still suffers from his/her racial disadvantages.

Devil's sight negating sunlight sensitivity? Also I haven't encountered any special information on that either. So the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

## ***No, it does not.***

Sunlight sensitivity and Superior Darkvision aren't mechanically connected, so Eyes of the Night doesn't remove Sunlight Sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

### No, it does not.

The Drow *Superior Darkvision* and *Sunlight Sensitivity* abilities don't say anything about each other, so replacing *Superior Darkvision* does nothing to *Sunlight Sensitivity*. Similarly, *Eyes of the Dark* and *Devil's Sight* don't mention it either, so they have no effect (although *Devil's Sight* is better than standard Darkvision since it allows better vision in darkness than Darkvision and allows the character to see through magical darkness). *Eyes of the Dark* will have no effect on a Drow, since they already have *Superior Darkvision*, which is identical in all ways except name.

It is worthwhile to note that, technically speaking (and according to RAW), *Sunlight Sensitivity* has nothing to do with sun being in the character's eyes, since it applies

> when you, the target of your attack, or whatever you are trying to perceive is in direct sunlight.

This means that a Drow character would suffer the effects of *Sunlight Sensitivity* simply by standing in sunlight, even if their eyes and whatever they're looking at are both in shade.

On the other hand, the intensity of any given light doesn't factor in, given that they have no listed weaknesses to bright light, light-based effects, or anything else that isn't direct sunlight. Presumably this means that Drow in 5e are assumed (setting permitting) to have some sort of hereditary magical curse granting them penalties in sunlight, rather than their eyes simply not being accustomed to bright light, but I don't know of any official sources that comment on the matter one way or the other.

That said, many DMs houserule things (or have a homebrew setting with different circumstances for the Drow) so that Drow simply have eyes that are vulnerable to bright sunlight and, therefore, simply need to shade their eyes somehow (and avoid looking at or attacking targets in bright sunlight). Talk to your DM to see how they plan on handling *Sunlight Sensitivity* and maybe they'll have an idea that works for you.